# Не работает фоновая задача на Android 9+

Tags: android

С переходом приложения с targetSdkVersion 26 на 28 перестал работать класс (MyParsing.class) для обработки парсинга, который вызывался из AsyncTask. Добавил в манифест `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />` - не помогло. MyParsing я через Service не запускаю, потому что в сервисе другой код работает, но я вызывал этот класс и через Service - тоже не работает. Если запускаю на эмуляторе или устройстве с API 26 то работает MyParsing, если запускаю на эмуляторе 28 то не работает. Если в Gradle targetSdkVersion понижаю с 28 до 26 то MyParsing  на устройстве с API 28 уже работает. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы MyParsing работал на устройстве с API 28 и на targetSdkVersion 28 ?

Comment: Добавьте конкретики, пожалуйста. Пока не ясно, что значит "перестал работать класс" - какой-то метод не вызывается? Или происходят ошибки при вызове? Можно так же добавить код `MyParsing.java`

Comment: решение нашел тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55386631/httpurlconnection-with-json-on-android-9-api-28